# Chain iterable with strip

Tags: python

Is it possible to strip the iterable below without resorting to a list comprehension?

```
>>> values=f.df['AvailableInTerritories'].tolist()
>>> values
['AU, CA,GB,US', 'AU, CA, GB, US', 'AU, AT, CA, GB, US', 'AU, CA, GB, US', 'AU, CA, GB, US']
>>> list_separator=','

>>> [item.strip() for item in itertools.chain.from_iterable((str(_val).split(list_separator) for _val in values))]
['AU', 'CA', 'GB', 'US', 'AU', 'CA', 'GB', 'US', 'AU', 'AT', 'CA', 'GB', 'US', 'AU', 'CA', 'GB', 'US', 'AU', 'CA', 'GB', 'US']
```

Comment: Use `map`? Use a for-loop? What is it exactly that you are trying to avoid?

Comment: `', '.join(values).replace(',', ' ').split()` works too

Answer (score 2):

Change your `list_separator` to `', '`, so you don't need to use `strip()`:

```
list_separator = ', '
```

And then use:

```
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable((str(_val).split(list_separator) for _val in values)))
['AU', 'CA', 'GB', 'US', 'AU', 'CA', 'GB', 'US', 'AU', 'AT', 'CA', 'GB', 'US', 'AU', 'CA', 'GB', 'US', 'AU', 'CA', 'GB', 'US']
```

---

I assume you're interested in a non-list comprehension version. You can do:

```
values = ['AU, CA, GB, US', 'AU, CA, GB, US', 'AU, AT, CA, GB, US', 'AU, CA, GB, US', 'AU, CA, GB, US']
list_separator = ', '

lst = []
for x in values:
    lst.extend(x.split(list_separator))

print(lst)
# ['AU', 'CA', 'GB', 'US', 'AU', 'CA', 'GB', 'US', 'AU', 'AT', 'CA', 'GB', 'US', 'AU', 'CA', 'GB', 'US', 'AU', 'CA', 'GB', 'US']
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need `itertools.chain`, there's another much cleaner and efficient solution:

```
print([x for i in values for x in i.split(', ')])
```

Output:

```
['AU', 'CA', 'GB', 'US', 'AU', 'CA', 'GB', 'US', 'AU', 'AT', 'CA', 'GB', 'US', 'AU', 'CA', 'GB', 'US', 'AU', 'CA', 'GB', 'US']
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using `re.split`

```
import re
print (re.split(',\s*', ','.join(values)))
#['AU', 'CA', 'GB', 'US', 'AU', 'CA', 'GB', 'US', 'AU', 'AT', 'CA', 'GB', 'US', 'AU', 'CA', 'GB', 'US', 'AU', 'CA', 'GB', 'US']
```